# pyspark append very large multiple dataframes after each process under for loop (eg: append after daily ETL)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have to do ETL for each day and then add it to a single dataframe. 
Eg: After each day ETL following are the outputs..

```
df1: 
    id category quantity date
    1   abc       100    01-07-18
    2   deg       175    01-07-18
    .....
df2: 
    id category quantity date
    1   abc       50     02-07-18
    2   deg       300    02-07-18
    3   zzz       250    02-07-18
    .....
df3: 
    id category quantity date
    1   abc       500    03-07-18
    .....
df4: 
    id category quantity date
    5   jjj       200    04-07-18
    7   ddd       100    04-07-18
    .....
```

For each day ETL, one dataframe need to be created like df1,df2,df3,... and after each day ETL that dataframe should be appneded with earlier dates ETL..

Final output expected:

```
After day 2 output should be:
 finaldf: 
        id category quantity date
        1   abc       100    01-07-18
        2   deg       175    01-07-18
        1   abc       50     02-07-18
        2   deg       300    02-07-18
        3   zzz       250    02-07-18
        .....


After day 4 output should be:
     finaldf: 
            id category quantity date
            1   abc       100    01-07-18
            2   deg       175    01-07-18
            1   abc       50     02-07-18
            2   deg       300    02-07-18
            3   zzz       250    02-07-18
            1   abc       500    03-07-18
            5   jjj       200    04-07-18
            7   ddd       100    04-07-18
            .....
```

I have done this using `Pandas using append function` but as the data size is very large I am getting MemoryError.

Comment: Are you working with `spark` dataframes?

Comment: yes with spark @pault

Answer (score 0):

Answer for PySpark

Put all the DataFrames into a list

```
df_list = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
finaldf = reduce(lambda x, y: x.union(y), df_list)
```

finaldf will contain all the data.